# DataGridView not displaying my List

Tags: c#, winforms, list, datagridview

Although there are a lot of posts on this site about populating a gridview with objects, I can't get it working.

I have a class called Logs with 3 public properties - Time, Description and Error.
There is also a public property called logList that will return a List of Logs Objects.

And I have DataGridView in my WinForm, called myGV, with 3 columns called Time, Description and Error.

So I'm trying:

```
myGV.DataSource = Logs.logList.OrderBy(x => x.Time);
```

But my DataGridView displays nothing, even though logList does contain data.

Thanks for your work on this site!

UPDATE:
If I remove all columns from myGV it does display data.  So how do match static columns to the properties in my List of Objects?

Comment: How are your columns "called" something?

Comment: Also, are you using WinForms or WPF?

Comment: The column's 'Name' property is set to Time, Description and Error.

Comment: What type is your logList?  Is it a List<>, Array, ...?  (Even better, can you please post your Logs class?)

Comment: Take a look at this exemple if it can help you setup the binding differently:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/125109/winforms-datagridview-binding-to-a-listt
(Take a look at the answer by Jared)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's strange that you said *`If I remove all columns from myGV it does display data...`*. I reproduced your problem and the reason is your `LINQ` query is not executed. You have to call `ToList()` or similar method before using the result as `DataSource` of your `DataGridView`:

```
myGV.DataSource = Logs.logList.OrderBy(x => x.Time).ToList();
```

Of course, If your static columns don't have `DataPropertyName` matched with the properties of the DataSource, there will be more columns added to your `DataGridView` than you expect. For example, suppose all the `Time`, `Description` and `Error` are added at design time without assigning any `DataPropertyName` and `yourDataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = true` (by default), if you assign the `DataSource` of your `DataGridView` as above, your `DataGridView` may have 6 columns at all, instead of 3. So you can assign the `DataPropertyName` of your added columns before assigning the `DataSource` for your `DataGridView`, something like this:

```
myGV.Columns["Time"].DataPropertyName = "Time";
myGV.Columns["Description"].DataPropertyName = "Description";
myGV.Columns["Error"].DataPropertyName = "Error";
myGV.DataSource = Logs.logList.OrderBy(x => x.Time).ToList();//This should be called at here after all the DataPropertyNames are initialized.
```

I recommend you to set `myGV.AutoGenerateColumns = true` (by default) and remove all the added columns, just let the `DataGridView` auto-generate columns for you.

Comment: Thanks! Setting the DataPropertyName was necessary, but the problem was that LINQ was not executed as per your suggestion.  Adding ToList() did the trick.

Answer (score 3):

After you manually add the columns, you have to make sure you update the `DataPropertyName` of each one of them:

- Click in the little arrow on top of your DataGridView, to display the Control's Tasks.
  [image]
- Click on **Edit Columns**.
- For each of your columns find the property `DataPropertyName` and change them to `Date`, `Error` and `Description` and whatever other names you have used for your columns. 
  [image]

Make sure these match with your `Properties` in your Logs class.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the complete and concise answer.  This by itself did not work, although it was definitely part of the problem.  I had to call ToList() as per King Kongs answer below.

Answer (score 0):

OrderBy() returns IOrderedEnumerable<> type of data, that are not bindable to DataGridView.
So you have to cast them to a Binding Source.
Use ToList() method like
"OrderBy().ToList()" to bind your gridview.
    `dataGridView1.DataSource = studList.OrderBy(a => a.Age).ToList();`

It is working 
[image: Screenshot]

For more info to bind DataGridView visit [dataGridView binding](http://dotprogramming.blogspot.com/2013/06/how-to-bind-datagridview-in-windows.html)